# Solid background color for text

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to create this effect with either CSS3 or jQuery?

[image: img]

Comment: Yes, yes it is. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dUBkn/1/  only works in webkit tough ... xD

Answer (score 2):

It really is a presentational problem, so for the sake of your users and of [Progressive enhancement](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/22/progressive-enhancement-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it/), this is a task better handled by CSS and not JavaScript.

You can do a [`text-stroke` declaration](http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/ZQ7Gx/). Unfortunately, it is WebKit-only for now.

```
-webkit-text-stroke:2px white;
```

Plus, in your specific example, you need to align the stroke outside the text, which is impossible right now.

From [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/):

> Only outside text stroke alignment looks any good at all to me. It's
>   unfortunate, both for CSS and for Illustrator, that the unchangeable
>   default is centered.

You can always [stack up `text-shadow` declarations](http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/vBhCp/) in all directions to achieve this effect. This is a bit messier than text-stroke, but browser support is better (for now).

```
text-shadow:  0 1px 0 white, 0 2px 0 white,
              1px 0 0 white, 2px 0 0 white,
              -1px 0 0 white, -2px 0 0 white,
              0px -1px 0 white, 0 -2px 0 white;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible with the help of text-shadow. Like this:

```
.MyDiv{
 background:green;
 padding:20px 20px;
 color:black;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 3px white, 
                0px 0px 4px white, 
                0px 0px 5px white,
                0px 0px 6px white, 
                0px 0px 7px white,
                0px 0px 8px white, 
                0px 0px 9px white,
                1px 1px 2px white, 
                1px 1px 3px white,
                -1px -1px 2px white, 
                -1px -1px 3px white,
                -2px -2px 2px white,
                -2px -2px 3px white;}​
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rCWPU/1/). You can keep adding definitions to strengthen the effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with CSS3:

```
#element {
    color: red;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mraQq/)